# How to add a Bootstrap tooltip to a checkbox?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, checkbox, tooltip

I've successfully added Bootstrap tooltips to a learning project I'm doing. So far only applied to link tags:

```html
<a href="#" data-toggle="tooltip" data-original-title="My Popup text">
    Foobar
</a>
```

But I've got some checkboxes that need some explaining. I can't find any examples of Bootstrap tooltips for checkboxes. Is this a do-able thing?

If I have the following:

```html
<label>
    <input type="checkbox" id="foo" /> Foobar
</label>
```

I tinkered a bit but got nowhere trying to add popups to the checkbox.

Suggestions?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

This does not have any different method. Simply done like:

```
<input type='checkbox' data-toggle='tooltip' data-placement='right' data-original-title="tooltip here" class='checkbox'/>
```

Check if you make all tooltip element initialized via jQuery. Put this in the `head`:

```
<script>
    $(function () {
        $("[data-toggle='tooltip']").tooltip();
    });
</script>
```

And in case you didn't know, disabled checkboxes do not show tooltip. Also check if your checkboxes are disabled or not.

Comment: That did the trick. Though, as you have it there, it only shows the tool tip if you're on the check-box itself. I moved the code you suggested to the <label> tag and the whole thing improved. Thank you much.

Comment: If that works you could mark it as an Accepted Answer. @Argle

Comment: That doesn't work if the checkbox is disabled though.

Comment: @pierrea found that if you execute the code `$("[data-toggle='tooltip']").tooltip();` in the console it works for disabled also, but can't find a way to make it work correctly by itself. I've ended up with a setInterval() function which executes that code ... and worked.